# Aurelia require html import not working

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I have no errors in the console. But the console is not logging a `console.log` I put in the constructor of the `top-nav.js`. But more importantly. The simple jumbotron div is not rendering, Aurelia says in the console that it found the correct `top-nav.html` though. Here is the `App.html`

```
<template>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <require from="htmlreq/top-nav"></require>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

`App.js` for consistency

```
export class App {
    message = "Hello Pathways";
}
```

`top-nav.html`

```
<template>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container"> 
            <p>Career &amp; Technical Education </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

`top-nav.js` the console statement is not firing. And the Jumbotron is not visible or listed anywhere in the dom.

```
export class TopNav {
    _topnav = true;
    constructor() {
        console.log('constructed');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are "requiring" the custom element but you are not "using" it.

You should do this:

```
<template>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <require from="htmlreq/top-nav"></require>
    <h1>${message}</h1>

    <top-nav></top-nav>
</template>
```

No need to use `compose` in this case.

Comment: As always, Fabio with the awesome answer!

Comment: haha, thank you @AshleyGrant! Someday I'll be as awesome as you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it looks like this is a case for `<compose>`. It "composes" the html, and you can still do some view-model view binding business if you wanted to. I need this on the App.html instead of the require. Require, I think, is more for creating custom attributes/tags, and then including them in the `app.html`

```
<template>
    <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
    <compose view-model="htmlreq/top-nav" view.bind="htmlreq/top-nav.html"></compose>
    <h1>${message}</h1>
</template>
```

Comment: Please don't use compose for this. This is not a case of dynamic composition, which is pretty much the only time compose should be used.